# Replace dynamic with generics when using ComInterop

Tags: c#, generics, com-interop

I have a bunch of classes that wrap a ComInterop object from a 3rd-party aplication. Below pseudo-code illustrates the setup

```
class BaseWrapper : IBaseWrapper
{
    // some classes that derived classes must implement
    public abstract object[] GetRow(int i);
    public abstract string Foo(string s)
    public abstract string Bar(int i, string s)
}

class WrapperA : BaseWrapper
{
    ExternalComApp.IComInteropObjectA a = ..some COM object A..
    public override object[] GetRow(int i)
    {
        return a.GetRow(i).ToArray<object>();
    }
    public override string Foo(string s)
    {
        return a.Foo(s);
    }
    public override string Bar(int i, string s)
    {
        return a.Bar(i, s);
    }
    public string JustInA()
    {
        return a.MethodX();
    }
}

class WrapperB : BaseWrapper
{
    ExternalComApp.IComInteropObjectB b = ..some COM object B.. 
    public override object[] GetRow(int i)
    {
        return b.GetRow(i).ToArray<object>();
    }
    public override string Foo(string s)
    {
        return b.Foo(s);
    }
    public override string Bar(int i, string s)
    {
        return b.Bar(i, s);
    }
}
```

In reality, the method bodies are larger. `IComInteropObjectA` and `IComInteropObjectB` are supplied by the ComInterop assembly I talk to. The issue is that there is a lot of repetition going on here.

`IComInteropObjectA` and `IComInteropObjectB` share a number of identical methods. My goal is to eliminate some of the repetition by moving the methods that the ComInterop objects share to the `BaseWrapper` class.

I managed to do that, example for `GetRow` in `BaseWrapper`:

```
protected internal object[] GetRow(dynamic obj, int i)
{
    return obj.GetRow(i);
}
```

I can call that from the derived classes by passing either `a` or `b`. However, using `dynamic` has severe disadvantages (the least of my worries but still important: it makes my assembly slower) and I would like to avoid it if possible.

My question: is there a way to achieve this without using the `dynamic` keyword? I tried to use generics and failed, I'm not even sure the concept of generics applies here.

Comment: Can you modify `IComInteropObjectA` and `IComInteropObjectA` definitions ? i.e. to add another interface ?

Comment: No, they are part of a 3rd-party application. I updated the question to reflect that.